# Fetch row one at a time and put the value in each <td>

Tags: php, sql, database

Searching for week not found any solution about this type of query. I want to fetch 2 row value which separated by "," in each `<td>`. I want to fetch both value in each `<td></td>` e.g. Size M and Colour Red in one `<td>`.

In database I store value for Size and colour separately. **Size : M,L,XL and Colour: Pink,Red,Green.**

```
<?
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE usr='Test'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
$options1 = explode(',',$row['val']);
foreach($options1 AS $option1)
{
 echo "<td><name>" . $row['name'] . "</Name>\n";
 echo "<Value>$option1</Value>\n</td>";
 }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I want out link this -

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <Name>Size</Name>
            <Value>S</Value>    
            <Name>Color</Name>
            <Value>Pinks</Value>
        </td>
        <td>
            <Name>Size</Name>
            <Value>M</Value>
            <Name>Color</Name>
            <Value>Red</Value>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Size and colour value need to be go in each .

I am getting Result -

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <Name>Size</Name>
            <Value>S</Value>  
            <Name>Size</Name>
            <Value>M</Value>                

        </td>
        <td>
            <Name>Color</Name>
            <Value>Pinks</Value>
            <Name>Color</Name>
            <Value>Red</Value>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Put the echo <td> outside of the loop

Comment: I tried that but not the same output I am looking for (above) - I want size and colour value together in each <td></td>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE usr='Test'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    $options1 = explode(',',$row['val']);
    echo "<td>";
    foreach($options1 AS $option1){
        echo "<name>" . $row['name'] . "</Name>\n";
        echo "<Value>$option1</Value>\n";
    }
    echo "</td>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: It tried with that - Result - one row value going in one <td>                         <table>
<td>
<name>Size</Name>
<Value>S</Value>
<name>Size</Name>
<Value>M</Value>
<name>Size</Name>
<Value>L</Value>
</td>
<td>
<name>Colour</Name>
<Value>Black</Value>
<name>Colour</Name>
<Value>Yellow</Value>
<name>Colour</Name>
<Value>Red</Value>
</td>
</table>

Comment: I want size and colour value together in each <td></td>.

Comment: have change assoc with row. Try again.

Comment: Result - Blank - <td><name></Name>
<Value></Value>
</td><td><name></Name>
<Value></Value>
</td> i tried with - mysqli_fetch_array also but same result

Comment: Can you please update your question and tell me how the table looks like? I think I found the problem. I thought you have a table with: id, size, color, usr. But your table looks like id,name,val,usr, right?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for late reply. I have updated the result.. Please check